# How to avoid two max in sql statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query to be executed, but still, have two Max in one SQL statement. I want to rectify that issue.

```
SELECT * FROM persons s INNER JOIN   ( 
  SELECT s1.person_id, 
         MAX(s1.run_number * power(2,64)  + s1.transaction_id) as CEILING_ID, 
         MAX(message_sequence) as MSG_SEQUENCE  
  FROM persons S1 
  WHERE s1.run_number * power(2,64) + s1.transaction_id < 2497 * power(2,64) + 172 
  GROUP BY s1.person_id 
) m ON s.person_id = m.person_id AND 
       s.run_number * power(2,64) + s.transaction_id = m.CEILING_ID 
WHERE s.person_id = 'L1001001' AND 
      s.status != '2' AND 
      s.MESSAGE_SEQUENCE = m.MSG_SEQUENCE
```

Thank you

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: Two Max, but in the same Select, why do you think it's bad? You can probably get the same result avoiding the self-join with Windowed Aggregates.

Comment: When two max is there, is it guaranteed that max is select from first group, and the second max is from the first group?

Comment: The two max are independent from each other. One is the maximum message sequence, the other the maximum expression result. You can have many aggregation results in the same query, i.e. many `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc. Why shouldn't you?

Comment: Anyhow, above query has given empty resultset. Is there any difference between using MAX(s1.message_sequence) and MAX(message_sequence) in above mentioned SQL?

Comment: Are you wanting to find the row with the latest message_sequence, and use the ceiling_id based on that row (or vice versa)? If so, use the analytic row_number() function to identify the latest row, and use that in your join condition.

Comment: It is vice versa, use the ceiling_id to filter the set and find the row with the latest message_sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If `transaction_id` is always less than `POWER(2,64)` then you appear to be finding the maximum `message_sequence` for the most recent `run_number` and `transaction_id` and you could write it using analytic functions as:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE persons ( person_id, run_number, transaction_id, message_sequence, status ) AS
SELECT 'L1001001', 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'L1001001', 1, 2, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'L1001001', 2, 1, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'L1001001', 2, 2, 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'L1001001', 2, 3, 4, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         MAX( message_sequence )
           KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY run_number, transaction_id )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY person_id )
           AS message_for_max_rn_ti,
         MAX( message_sequence )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY person_id )
           AS max_message_sequence
  FROM   persons p
  WHERE  person_id = 'L1001001'
  AND    (  run_number < 2497
         OR ( run_number = 2497 AND transaction_id < 172 ) )
)
WHERE message_sequence = max_message_sequence
AND   status != 2;
```

**Output**:

```
PERSON_ID | RUN_NUMBER | TRANSACTION_ID | MESSAGE_SEQUENCE | STATUS | MESSAGE_FOR_MAX_RN_TI | MAX_MESSAGE_SEQUENCE
:-------- | ---------: | -------------: | ---------------: | -----: | --------------------: | -------------------:
L1001001  |          2 |              2 |                5 |      1 |                     4 |                    5
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=da8abd2c64e4a901459ed4e0e6bd3d22)*